# Populating A field with data from the sql database in Android?

Tags: android, database

I am building an Android app & one of the functions I need is to list vehicles and other  related data for example manufacturers and models etc...
I am hoping to be able to retreive data from the sql database in Android & I am building the
app using Eclipse.
I would like the data once retrieved from the sql database to appear in a text type field if possible can anyone help me.
I have done some basic research on this but I am a bit stumped help would be greattly appreciated.
Many Thanks
Will.

Comment: http://d.android.com first - read guide ... Then look at SDK samples ApiDemo search for listview + cursoradapter ...

Comment: Great I will have a look at your reccomendation if I get into diffculties with it I will ask for clarification and again many thanks.

Comment: I found the NotePad sample very helpful when I was learning Android.

Comment: Hi Philip Sheard : I have strarted the notepad tutorial after all the advise I have had so far including yours. I am realising the notepad tutorial will allow me to get to grips with the concepts of the sql database etc.... So I will add comment when I have finished the tutorials from both sources I have been given. Thanks for your concise and helpful reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since this is your first question, I'll be helping you.
On StackOverflow, people here are willing to help you but you must help them too.
You need to do two things:

1. Make your question clear as what you are trying to do and what is your problem. Which you did.
2. Make people feel you made an effort to resolve your problem. I'm sorry but I dont feel it. It's probably why your question is marked down as well. You see the arrow up and down on the left of each question and answer? That's exactly it. I did not mark you down though.

Anyway, you should be able to find what you need here:  http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

This article explain how to use SQLite3 on Android much better than I can do. Good luck :)

Comment: I am going to check out that vogella link and report back my results/progress when I have done this. Many Thanks.

Comment: I have just been to that link showing the tutorial by Lars Vogel I am going to work through this tutorial step by step it looks like exactly what I am looking for I have followed the sql examples in android but some of the steps dont seem to work so this looks more like what I need Many Thanks and thanks for wishing me luck!